# PHP or HTML or CSS Image scale from Original Max Height 100, but scale width to auto;

Tags: php, html, css

Ether Using, PHP, HTML or CSS.

I have a image lets say "1642 x 351" I would like it to auto scale the width but max height of 100,

so the final image would : 467 x 100;

The main code i am doing is Part PHP and part CSS.

PHP:

```php
<?php
$size = getimagesize($tmpfilename);
$imgwidth = $size[0];
$imgheight = $size[1];
$imgwidthhalf = $imgwidth/2;
?>
```

CSS:

```
<style>
.widget-4 .card-profile-img {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    pointer-events: none;
    left: 50%;
    top: 25px;
    margin-left: <?= $imgwidthhalf; ?>px;
}
</style>
```

(note: Yes I know that $imgwidthhalf = $imgwidth/2; is not gonna give right scale.)

Comment: Well the problem is i need the Image to be centered in page, i have a Image one size, i want to resize it to max height of 100px, then i need to do Left: 50%;  but to bring it back to center of image i need to do :   -Image width / 2 = margin-left .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the Solution might as well answer my own post.

```
<?php

    $size = getimagesize($tmpfilename);
    $imgWidth = $size[0]; // Get current Width of image.
    $imgHeight = $size[1]; // Get current Height of image.
    
    $aspect = ($imgWidth / $imgHeight); // Get Aspect Ratio, Width / Height.
    
    
    // Optional set new Height or New Width.
    
    $setNewHeight = 100;
    $setNewWidth = 200;
    
    
    // To get Width of image to be auto aspect ratio of a new Height:
    $newWidth = ($setNewHeight * $aspectRatio);
    
    
    // To get Height of image to be auto aspect ratio of a new Width:
    $newHeight = ($setNewWidth / $aspectRatio);
    
    ?>
```